# Bootstrap - Align horizontal forms in different column width containers

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

Does anyone know if there is a way in Bootstrap 3.3.7 to align horizontal forms in 2 different containers with different column widths:
    https://codepen.io/adbarnes/pen/aGbYYe

```
    <body>
    <div class="container">
    <br><br>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-12">
        <div class="panel panel-default">
          <div class="panel-body">
            <form class="form-horizontal">
              <div class="col-md-12">
                <div class="form-group">
                  <label for="inputEmail3" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Email</label>
                  <div class="col-sm-10">
                    <input type="email" class="form-control" id="inputEmail3" placeholder="Email">
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                  <label for="inputPassword3" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Password</label>
                  <div class="col-sm-10">
                    <input type="password" class="form-control" id="inputPassword3" placeholder="Password">
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                  <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-10">
                    <div class="checkbox">
                      <label>
                      <input type="checkbox"> Remember me         </label>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                  <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-10">
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Sign in</button>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </form>

          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-12">
        <div class="panel panel-default">
          <div class="panel-body">
            some other content here some other content here some other content here some other content here some other content here some other content here some other content here some other content here some other content here some other content here some other
            content here some other content here
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <!-- 2nd -->

      <div class="col-md-9">
        <div class="panel panel-default">
          <div class="panel-body">

            <form class="form-horizontal">
              <div class="col-md-12">
                <div class="form-group">
                  <label for="inputEmail3" class="col-sm-3 control-label">Email</label>
                  <div class="col-sm-9">
                    <input type="email" class="form-control" id="inputEmail3" placeholder="Email">
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                  <label for="inputPassword3" class="col-sm-3 control-label">Password</label>
                  <div class="col-sm-9">
                    <input type="password" class="form-control" id="inputPassword3" placeholder="Password">
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                  <div class="col-sm-offset-3 col-sm-9">
                    <div class="checkbox">
                      <label>
                      <input type="checkbox"> Remember me</label>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                  <div class="col-sm-offset-3 col-sm-9">
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Sign in</button>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </form>

          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-3">
        <div class="panel panel-default">
          <div class="panel-body">
            <img src="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAIAAAHd3dwAAACH5BAAAAAAALAAAAAABAAEAAAICRAEAOw==" width="200" height="200" class="img-responsive" alt="Generic placeholder thumbnail">
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>


</body>
```

In the example posted I want to align the forms. I understand that each label's width is 16.6% of a different total width but i'm wondering if there is a way around this?

Many thanks

Comment: Not sure what you are asking. You need the second panel with inputs to use different column widths?

Comment: No, I want to align the 2 different forms https://imgur.com/a/3kcSLCM

Comment: I see what you are trying now... Seems like some row padding/margin is added. Check if you can remove the extra space on a parent element. I often use things like .pl0 (padding left 0) or .pl10 to adjust padding on some elements.